# Threads in C, How to create 2 threads that will recieve messages by IPC

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I've created 2 threads, one of them should summarize random numbers and display average of  them, second must multiply them and display them too. After compiling and running it only making something like this:[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iry1V.jpg), can someone help, how to do this? Thread1 is function that summarize and display average of random numbers, Thread2 is function that multiplies random numbers

```
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sched.h>
#include<sys/ipc.h>
#include<sys/msg.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<time.h>

struct msgbuf {
    long type;
    int data;
};

void *thread_1(void *id)
{
    static int i=0;
    struct msgbuf buffer;
    static int sum=0;
    static double arytm=0;
    if(msgrcv(*(int*)id,&buffer,sizeof(buffer.data),1,0)<0)
        perror("msgrcv");
    else
        {
            sum=sum+buffer.data;
            arytm=sum/(i+1);
            printf("Thread 1 Srednia arytm %f\n",arytm);
            i=i+1;
        }
    return NULL;
}


void *thread_2(void *id)
{
    struct msgbuf buffer;
    static unsigned long long iloczyn=1;
    if(msgrcv(*(int*)id,&buffer,sizeof(buffer.data),1,0)<0)
        perror("msgrcv");
    else
        {
            iloczyn=iloczyn*buffer.data;
            printf("Thread 2 Iloczyn %llu\n",iloczyn);
        }
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int j,random;
    pthread_t thread_id[2];
    int key = ftok("/tmp",8);
    if(key<0)
        perror("ftok");

    int id = msgget(key,0600|IPC_CREAT|IPC_EXCL);
    if(id==-1)
        {
        id=msgget(key,0600|IPC_CREAT);
        if(id==-1)
            perror("msgget");
        }
    struct msgbuf buffer;



    for(j=0;j<20;j++)
    {
        printf("Iteracja nr %d\n",j+1);
        random=128+ rand()%128;
        printf("Random number %d\n",random);
            buffer.type=1;
        buffer.data= random;
        if(msgsnd(id,&buffer,sizeof(buffer.data),0)<0)
            perror("msgsnd");

                    int return_code = pthread_create(&(thread_id[0]),NULL,thread_1,(void *)&id);
                        if(return_code!=0)
                            fprintf(stderr,"pthread_create() error: %d\n",return_code);
                    int return_code1= pthread_create(&(thread_id[1]),NULL,thread_2,(void *)&id);
                        if(return_code1!=0)
                            fprintf(stderr,"pthread_create() error: %d\n",return_code1);
        sleep(1);
    }
    if(msgctl(id,IPC_RMID,0)<0)
        perror("msgctl");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: They're threads.  Why use IPC?

Comment: Why are you creating 40 threads?

Comment: 'Thread1 is function that summarize and display average of random numbers' umm no?  If it's gong to sum things, it should have a loop somewhere.

Comment: I can't make any sense of this design at all:(

Comment: How should this be, i don't really understand threads, maybe you have some ideas?

Comment: I need to make a program where 3 threads would be created: 1 main and 2 supporting. Main Thread should send to supporting threads 20 random numbers every second. Supporting should recieve that numbers. First supporting thread must summarize numbers and display average, second supporting thread should multiply that numbers and display them, for communication i should use message queue.

Comment: Educate yourself on threads in C by reading general material on the web and studying examples.  Then you may be able to restructure your code to work or ask specific questions that can be answered here.